# Como gerar um qrCode a partir de uma url

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, qrcode

**url** = https://staging.coinwise.io/api/invoice/v1/invoice/koy-intel-juridica/default-btc?value=0.05

**Json:**
{"id":10,"BTC":{"value":0.00000189,"address":"1BUPDHmaAnVDzAq7rBuv1UW1vXFQhhsgZx","qrcode":"data:image/png;base64,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"},"BRL":{"value":"0.05","rates":{"BTC":26450.328099999995}}}
json =

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar essa [lib](https://davidshimjs.github.io/qrcodejs/).

Basta seguir essa ideia.

```
 function qrCodeExample(url) {
  var qrcode = new QRCode(document.getElementById("qrcode"), {
    text: url,
    width: 70,
    height: 70,
    colorDark: "#000000",
    colorLight: "#ffffff",
    correctLevel: QRCode.CorrectLevel.H
  });
}
```

Depois é carregar, por exemplo, é uma *< div >* o contéudo do qrcode:

```
    <div id="qrcode" align="center">
     </div>
```

Comment: Estou usando o angular, como seria ?

Comment: @alexjosesilva da uma olhada nos exemplos do link que passei, lá vai lhe orientar melhor. Mas é basicamente, você carregar o a lib .js do QrCode no seu projeto, Condiciona sua função de gerar QrCode de acordo a sua necessidade e aplica a <div> na página que vc quer q carregue o QrCode.